# Scroll from top 10rem down

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple questions about the `document.querySelector(this.getAttribute("href")).scrollIntoView`

I want to write a snippet sroll to top minus 10rem.

I found a snippet for scroll to to top which works fine. But I have a fixed header in my project. scrollIntoView can't move the side 10rem down. How do I get the first line of my Side 10rem under the header. I do not want use jquery.

```
<script>
      document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
        anchor.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          document.querySelector(this.getAttribute("href")).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to get the `scrollTop` position of `document.querySelector(this.getAttribute("href"))` and add your 10rem to it, thenm scroll to that position...

Comment: Is it possible that you help me out with some lines of  javascript?